# Nuxt console.log() does not work although I set it in .eslintrc.js

Tags: vue.js, console, nuxt.js, eslint

I have a Nuxt application with .eslintrc.js file where I set up

```
rules: {
    "no-console": "off"
},
```

I expect it enables the console methods and I would be able to write to console. But it is still blocked. I dont know where else to set this option. nuxt.config.js does not contain lint section. thnakx for any help.

EDIT: Here is the nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
    // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
    head: {
        title: "lurity-portal-nuxt",
        htmlAttrs: {
            lang: "en",
        },
        meta: [
            { charset: "utf-8" },
            {
                name: "viewport",
                content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1",
            },
            { hid: "description", name: "description", content: "" },
            { name: "format-detection", content: "telephone=no" },
        ],
        link: [{ rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" }],
    },
    server: {
        port: process.env.PORT, // default: 3000
        host: process.env.HOST, // default: localhost
    },
    modern: true,
    // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
    css: [
        "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css",
        "@/assets/scss/bulma_styled.scss",
        "@/assets/scss/lurity.scss",
    ],
    router: {
        middleware: "auth",
    },
    // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
    plugins: [
        "~/plugins/helpers.js",
        "~/plugins/apiCalls.js",
        "~/plugins/vue-lazyload.client.js",
        { src: "~/plugins/vue-intersect.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/gmaps.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/google-auth.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/google-tag-manager.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/debounce.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/braintree.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/charts.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~/plugins/vuex-persist.client.js", mode: "client" },
        { src: "~plugins/leaflet.client.js", mode: "client" },
        "~/plugins/map-location.js",
    ],

    // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
    components: true,

    // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    buildModules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/eslint
        "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
        "@nuxtjs/composition-api/module",
    ],

    // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
    modules: [
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/buefy
        "nuxt-buefy",
        // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
        "@nuxtjs/axios",
        "@nuxtjs/proxy",
        [
            "nuxt-i18n",
            {
                locales: [
                    {
                        code: "en",
                        iso: "en-GB",
                        file: "en_locale.js",
                    },
                    {
                        code: "sk",
                        iso: "sk-SK",
                        file: "sk_locale.js",
                    },
                    {
                        code: "cz",
                        iso: "cs-CZ",
                        file: "cs_locale.js",
                    },
                ],
                defaultLocale: "en",
                strategy: "no_prefix",
                lazy: true,
                vueI18n: {
                    silentTranslationWarn: true,
                    silentFallbackWarn: true,
                },
                langDir: "locales/",
                // Enable browser language detection to automatically redirect user
                // to their preferred language as they visit your app for the first time
                // Set to false to disable
                detectBrowserLanguage: {
                    // If enabled, a cookie is set once a user has been redirected to his
                    // preferred language to prevent subsequent redirections
                    // Set to false to redirect every time
                    useCookie: true,
                    // Cookie name
                    cookieKey: "i18n_redirected",
                    // Set to always redirect to value stored in the cookie, not just once
                    alwaysRedirect: false,
                    // If no locale for the browsers locale is a match, use this one as a fallback
                    fallbackLocale: "en",
                },
            },
        ],
    ],
    buefy: { css: false, materialDesignIcons: false, defaultLocale: "sk-SK" },
    proxy: {
        // Simple proxy
        "/api": {
            target: `https://portal-api.lurity.com`,
        },
    },

    // Axios module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios
    axios: {
        proxy: true,
    },

    // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
    build: {
        transpile: ["vuex-stores"],
        loaders: {
            scss: {
                sourceMap: true,
                implementation: require("sass"),
                additionalData: `@import "~@/assets/scss/_bulma_variables.scss"; @import "~@/assets/scss/variables.scss";`,
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by "blocked"? What exactly are you trying to achieve? Remove the errors/warnings for it?

Comment: No t seems the console.log() writes to the terminal not to the browser console.

Comment: Yeah, it depends where you do write it and what are your project's settings. Can you share those parts please?

Comment: I have still problem with it. It is SSR (server side rendering) application NOT SPA (single page app). I dont know where to set it up. I can not debug the applications objects.

Comment: Can you please link your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: Sure there it is. Dont see any option related to this.

Comment: So, if you run `yarn dev`, can you see the `console.log()` into your terminal?

Comment: No, I dont see it in terminal nor in the browser. I found this page https://nuxtjs.org/blog/nuxtjs-from-terminal-to-browser but dont understand what it means "Forwarding Webpack build state right in the browser".

Comment: It means that you can see the progress of your app directly in your browser. Do you have a public repo for this?